# Correct parameter specifications for R map() function using do.call() in the function

Tags: r, dictionary, purrr, rlang, do.call

I've been working a on-line course and I've come to an exercise involving using rlang functions to produce the desired output. The suggested solution involved using a for() loop, but since an earlier part of the course involved purrr and map(), it seemed like a step backward to resort to a for() loop.

I have a tibble like so: (named "arguments")

```
# A tibble: 15 × 2
   fname .args                
   <chr> <chr>                
 1 rnorm n=10,mean=0,sd=3     
 2 rnorm n=100,mean=0,sd=3    
 3 rnorm n=1000,mean=0,sd=3   
 4 rnorm n=10000,mean=0,sd=3  
 5 rnorm n=100000,mean=0,sd=3 
 6 runif n=10,min=0,max=10    
 7 runif n=100,min=0,max=10   
 8 runif n=1000,min=0,max=10  
 9 runif n=10000,min=0,max=10 
10 runif n=100000,min=0,max=10
11 rexp  n=10,rate=2          
12 rexp  n=100,rate=2         
13 rexp  n=1000,rate=2        
14 rexp  n=10000,rate=2       
15 rexp  n=100000,rate=2
```

I wrote this function:

```
demo_1 <- function(func_name, arg_list){
   do.call(func_name, arg_list)
}
```

If I call the function like so:

```
demo_1(arguments$fname[[1]], as.list(strsplit(arguments$.args[[1]],",")))
```

I get the expected output:
[1] -0.4454785  0.6222901 -1.3134630

I've been struggling to feed these to map() for a week now, but can't work it out.
How do I pass these to map() to process the entire tibble, row by row?

Thanks.

Thanks to akrun for your efforts, but your code, while it works, is not what I was hoping to achieve.

I was looking to write a function which takes the function name as a string and the arguments as a string, then inside the function turn the function name into an actual function object and the arguments string into a set of arguments as appear in the .args column. Finally use something like do.call() to return the values generated by the function.

For example:

```
demo_2 <- function(.fname, .fargs){
     .... stuff I don't yet understand goes here
     fname <- ensym(.fname)?, enquo(.fname)?
     fargs <- ensym(.fargs)?, enquo(.fargs)?
     do.call(fname, fargs)
}
```

Once that has been created I wished to use some variant of the map family to pass each row of the data frame to that function.

I'm getting closer, but I still need some help. This function is nearly there, but I don't know how to map() it or how to change it to make it "map-able". Further advice gratefully received:

```
demo_3 <- function(.row, .data){
  x <- get(.data$fname[[.row]])
  y <- parse_exprs(.data$.args[[.row]])
  do.call(x,y)
}
```

Here is my latest iteration:

```
demo_4 <- function(.fname, .args){
  x <- get(.fname)
  y <- parse_exprs(.args)
  do.call(x,y)
}
```

When called with two string arguments:

```
> demo_4("rnorm", "n=10;mean=0;sd=3")
 [1]  0.4136818  1.3341674  2.1483943 -6.3195926  3.5595125 -0.9285594 -0.1743377 -0.7416142 -1.1671383 -2.6037147
```

When called with reference to the ***arguments*** tibble:
(I've changed the arguments$.args column to use a semi-colon separator instead of a comma separator.)

```
demo_4(arguments$fname[1], arguments$.args[1])
 [1]  4.1047325  1.4324751 -0.8754805 -0.4997726 -0.8513174  5.6490628 -2.7174594  4.4089390  0.1218752 -0.3962111
```

When calling with pmap() where the intention is to process each row in the tibble:

```
pmap(arguments, demo_4)
Error in `pmap()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `.f()`:
! unused argument (fname = .l[[1]][[i]])
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I don't understand the error message displayed when I run

```
rlang::last_error()
```

Is pmap() the wrong function to use? The help for pmap() tells me that if I use a data frame as the .l argument the called function should process each row. Plainly it doesn't so there's something I'm not seeing.

Suggestions?

Comment: I see that you are correct. The function should output 10 numbers for the first row of the tibble, not the three that my function returns. I don't immediately understand why, so I'll have to look into it. Taking a big leap now, presuming I fix the function so that it works, how do I use map() and NSE to make this work?

Comment: What does the tilde "~" do in the mutate() function? I can work out the other parts, but I'm only familiar with it's use in linear regression models and in the tribble() function.

Comment: It is a lambda expression (`function(x)`) compact option in tidyverse.  The default value is `.x` if there is a single argument, with multiple arguments it can be ..1, ..2, ..3, etc

Answer (score 0):

Use `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
arguments %>% 
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(new = list(demo_1(fname,  as.list(strsplit(.args,","))))) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 15 × 3
   fname .args                 new      
   <chr> <chr>                 <list>   
 1 rnorm n=10,mean=0,sd=3      <dbl [3]>
 2 rnorm n=100,mean=0,sd=3     <dbl [3]>
 3 rnorm n=1000,mean=0,sd=3    <dbl [3]>
 4 rnorm n=10000,mean=0,sd=3   <dbl [3]>
 5 rnorm n=100000,mean=0,sd=3  <dbl [3]>
 6 runif n=10,min=0,max=10     <dbl [3]>
 7 runif n=100,min=0,max=10    <dbl [3]>
 8 runif n=1000,min=0,max=10   <dbl [3]>
 9 runif n=10000,min=0,max=10  <dbl [3]>
10 runif n=100000,min=0,max=10 <dbl [3]>
11 rexp  n=10,rate=2           <dbl [2]>
12 rexp  n=100,rate=2          <dbl [2]>
13 rexp  n=1000,rate=2         <dbl [2]>
14 rexp  n=10000,rate=2        <dbl [2]>
15 rexp  n=100000,rate=2       <dbl [2]>
```

#### Update

By looking closely at the OP's function arguments, the output is not correct.  i.e. for the first row, it should return 10 observations as `n = 10` (showing the output for only the first 2 rows as `n` values are large in other rows)

```
library(purrr)
arguments %>%
   slice(1:2) %>%
    mutate(new = pmap(pick(everything()),
   ~ eval(rlang::parse_expr(sprintf('%s(%s)', ..1, ..2))))) %>%
    as_tibble
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
  fname .args             new        
  <chr> <chr>             <list>     
1 rnorm n=10,mean=0,sd=3  <dbl [10]> 
2 rnorm n=100,mean=0,sd=3 <dbl [100]>
```

---

Or without using the `eval/parse`

```
library(tidyr)
arguments %>% 
  mutate(rn = row_number())  %>% 
  slice(1:2)  %>%
  separate_longer_delim(`.args`, delim=",") %>% 
  separate_wider_delim(`.args`, names = c("arg_name", "value"), delim = "=") %>% 
 type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
 reframe(fname = first(fname), 
   value = list(as.list(setNames(value, arg_name))), .by = 'rn') %>% 
 rowwise %>% 
 mutate(new = list(demo_1(fname, value))) %>%
 ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 × 4
     rn fname value            new        
  <int> <chr> <list>           <list>     
1     1 rnorm <named list [3]> <dbl [10]> 
2     2 rnorm <named list [3]> <dbl [100]>
```

#### data

```
arguments <- structure(list(fname = c("rnorm", "rnorm", "rnorm", "rnorm", 
"rnorm", "runif", "runif", "runif", "runif", "runif", "rexp", 
"rexp", "rexp", "rexp", "rexp"), .args = c("n=10,mean=0,sd=3", 
"n=100,mean=0,sd=3", "n=1000,mean=0,sd=3", "n=10000,mean=0,sd=3", 
"n=100000,mean=0,sd=3", "n=10,min=0,max=10", "n=100,min=0,max=10", 
"n=1000,min=0,max=10", "n=10000,min=0,max=10", "n=100000,min=0,max=10", 
"n=10,rate=2", "n=100,rate=2", "n=1000,rate=2", "n=10000,rate=2", 
"n=100000,rate=2")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", 
"14", "15"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I've finally found a solution using the form I was looking for:

```
demo_4 <- function(.fname, .args){
  x <- get(.fname)
  y <- parse_exprs(.args)
  do.call(x,y)
}

pmap(arguments, ~ demo_4(..1, ..2))
```